# How to use Razor EditorFor Helper to create a TextBox with a value in from ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, viewbag

I simply want a text box editor field to appear with a value in it that has been passed with a ViewBag for example if ViewBag.Savings contained '6':

[image: editor field]

I tried something like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, ViewBag.Savings)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
```

I get the compiler error: '*Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'EditorFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.'*

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think EditorFor needs a model ->

```
@model Foo.Models.Savings
```

then

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
```

For ViewBag you could do:

```
@Html.TextBox("Savings", (string)ViewBag.Savings)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to cast ViewBag.Savings! Clue was in the error aha

Comment: Why does ViewBag.Savings need to be cast to string? I thought ViewBags didn't need casting.

Answer (score 0):

The `EditorFor` Html Helper wants a strongly typed object which a ViewBag is not. If you really want to use a ViewBag you would do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("savings", ViewBag.Savings)
```

Comment: @JimBarton You're getting the "'Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'EditorFor`" error still?